# Is there an easy VBA code using Split() Function to get a list of values for a combo box that was originally from a text box as a string?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

On my access form, I have a text box that will be a string of characters with multiple "/"s throughout the string. I want to use the split function to separate this string into a list of values to use for my combo box on a subform.

I know it's somewhere along the lines of:

```
Public Function MakeList()
Dim MyList as String
Dim txt as String

txt = [myTextBoxField].Value
MyList = Split(txt,"/")
```

Either:

```
[myComboBox].Value = MyList
```

Or:

```
[myTextBoxField].Value = MyList

End Sub
```

I am not sure if this is supposed to be on "Form Load" or in a module for the Public Function.

All other code shows a `For` Loop or `Debug.Print`. I am looking to store this list as a field in my table and then use that field for my Row Source in my combo box.

Comment: If it comes from `Split()`, `MyList` would be an array rather than a string. Declare it as `Dim MyList As Variant`

Comment: As far as your question goes, something like `ComboBox1.List = Split(txt)` in the form's initialize event should be enough.

Comment: Side note, the `[square-brackets]` shouldn't be needed, unless you use illegal characters to name your controls (e.g. whitespace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, combobox RowSourceType property must be set to ValueList. Next, VBA sets RowSource property, not Value. List is not a property of combobox in Access. Simply:

`Me.myComboBox.RowSource = Replace(Me.myTextBoxField, "/", ";")`

Form Load event should be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you all for your contribution. I am not very good at correct punctuation and format when it comes to code. The ComboBox is on a subform and the textbox is not. How would I refer to the combobox and its rowsource since Me.Combobox will not work? Something like Forms![Name of Subform].[Combobox Name].Rowsource? Too many "!" and "." that I put in the wrong spot. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @June7 this worked perfectly! I forgot to change the RowSource Type property to ValueList.